# Files storage on cloudbees

Tags: filesystems, cloudbees

My application requires storage for storing files like images and I dont want to store them in a database (neither RDBMS nor NoSQL) but as plain files. Is this possible?
Cheers
Mani

Answer (score 1):

File system isn't persistent, so content will be lost after a redeploy/restart.
A possible workaround is to use local filesystem for quick access to file resources but store them in amazon S3 (or any other storage service). You can use jClouds API to avoid lock-in with a provider API, and be able to run locally for testing purpose switching to FileSystem implementation